# Suggestion/feedback on database design for work order tracking in multiple stations

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I'm a student intern in a business team and my coworkers don't have the CS background so I hope to get some feedback and suggestion for improvement on the database design for the Flask web application that I will work on. Also, I self-learned sql a couple years ago by following tutorials on Youtube.

When a new work order is received by the business, it is then passed to a line of 5 stations to process it further. Currently the status of the work order is either started or finished. We hope to track it better by knowing the current station/stage (A, B, C, D, E) of the work order and then help improve the flow by letting the operator at each station know what's next in line.

My idea is create a web app (using Python 3, Flask, and postgresql) that updates the database when an operator at each station scans the work order's barcode and two other static barcodes (in_station_X and out_station_X). Each station will have a tablet connected to a scanner.

**I. Station Operator perspective (for example Station 1)**

- Scan the batch of all incoming work order (barcode) for that shift. For each item, they would also scan the in_station_1 barcode to record the `time_in` for each work order.
- The work orders come in queue so eventually the web app running on the tablet can show them what's next in line.
- When an item is processed, the operator would scan the work order again and also the out_station_1 barcode to record the `time_out` for each work order.
- The item coming out of that station may not have the same order as the incoming queue due to different `priority (boolean Yes/No)`.

**II. Admin/dashboard perspective:**

- See the current station and cycle time of each work order in that day.
- Modify the priority of a work order if needed be.
- Also, possibility to see reloop if a work order fails to be processed in station 2 and needs to go back to station 1.

**III. The database:**

a. Work Order Info table that contains fields such as:

```
id, workorder_barcode, requestor, priority (boolean Yes/No), date_created.
```

b. The Tracking Database: I'm thinking of having columns like:

```
 - id (automatically generated for new row)
 - workorder_barcode (nullable = False)
 - current_station (nullable = False)
 - time_in
 - time_out
```

I have several questions/concerns related to this tracking table:

1. Every time a work order is scanned in or out, a new row will be created (which mean either column is blank). Do you see any issues with this approach vs. looking up the same work order that has `time_in` to fill the `time_out`? The reason for this is to avoid multiple look up when the database scales big.
2. Since the app screen at each station will show what's next in line, do you think a simple query with `ORDER_BY` to show the the order needed would suffice? What concerns me is showing the next item based on both Priority of each item and the current incoming order. I think I can sort by multiple columns (`time_in and priority`) and `FILTER` by `current_station`. However, as you can see below, I think the current table design may be more suitable for capturing events than doing queue control.

   ---

For example: the table for today would look like

```
id, workorder_barcode, current_station, time_in, time_out

61, 100.1, A, 6:00pm, null
62, 100.3, A, 6:01pm, null
63, 100.2, A, 6:02pm, null
...
70, 100.1, A, null, 6:03pm
71, 100.1, B, 6:04pm, null
...
74, 100.5, C, 6:05pm, null
```

---

**At 6:05pm, the queue at each station would be**

```
Station A queue: 100.3, 100.2
Station B queue: 100.1
Station C queue: 100.5
```

3. I think this can get complicated to have all 5 stations sharing the same table but seeing different queues. Is there a Queue based database that you would recommend I look into?

Thank you so much for reading this. I appreciate any questions, comments, and suggestions since I'm trying to learn more about database as I get hands-on with this project.

Comment: Are you looking for `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: Thanks for responding @RickJames. Could you elaborate what part needs GROUP_CONCAT? My earlier questions asked more about the database design of the problem before actually querying...If there's something I could clarify, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Asking for "questions, comments, and suggestions" is not an on-topic question. [ask] Please ask a specific question about a specific question. Read & act on [mcve]. PS Read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design. Dozens are free online. Also presentations & courses.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461